# Conditional columns in select statement based on parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, select, parameters, conditional-statements

I have the below conditions:

```
- If ouk_shipment.shipper_parent_id = Parameter1 OR
ouk_shipment.shipper_id = Parameter2
=====> ouk_shipment.first_mwb_ref_id
- If ouk_shipment.cnee_parent_id = Parameter1 OR
ouk_shipment.cnee_id = Parameter2
=====> ouk_shipment.last_mwb_ref_id
```

**Parameter1 and Parameter2: we enter at run time of SQL.

I'm trying to achieve the following here:

```
Select case when condition 1=True then ouk_shipment.first_mwb_ref_id
            when condition 2=True then ouk_shipment.last_mwb_ref_id End AS Col1
From ouk_shipment
```

How to add conditions in my SQL?
Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 99% there

```
select 
  case 
    when ouk_shipment.shipper_parent_id = Parameter1 OR ouk_shipment.shipper_id = Parameter2 then ouk_shipment.first_mwb_ref_id
    when ouk_shipment.cnee_parent_id = Parameter1 OR ouk_shipment.cnee_id = Parameter2 then ouk_shipment.last_mwb_ref_id
  end col  
from  ouk_shipment
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do - note I did 'XXX' assuming it's varchar, you may change it to Integer for Int

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  ouk_shipment.shipper_parent_id = COALESCE(Parameter1,'XXX') 
                      OR ouk_shipment.shipper_id = COALESCE(Parameter2,'YYYY')
              THEN ouk_shipment.first_mwb_ref_id
            WHEN ouk_shipment.shipper_parent_id = COALESCE(Parameter1,'XXX') 
                OR ouk_shipment.shipper_id = COALESCE(Parameter2,'YYYY')
              THEN ouk_shipment.last_mwb_ref_id End AS Col1
FROM ouk_shipment
```

Comment: Wrong CASE syntax, I'm afraid.